# openssl decrypt issue fails with EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Tags: openssl

I am using `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` and I have a problem decrypting the data encrypted with openssl.

The encrypt command is

> openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -in
> in.txt -out out.dat

The decrypt command is

> openssl aes-256-cbc -d -md sha256 -salt -iter 100000 -pbkdf2 -in out.dat -out out.txt

The error is

> enter aes-256-cbc decryption password: bad
> decrypt 139749253547328:error:06065064:digital envelope
> routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:583:

Thanks

Comment: Well... see the difference? **-md sha512** and **-md sha256**. Let's say "*good morning to you and have a nice cup of coffee or tee*" :-)

Comment: @MichaelFehr omfg. thanks